# Does Lapras attack "Aqua Bullet" attack both Active and Benched Poémon?

Tags: pokemon

I have [Lapras](https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/sm-series/sm75/21/) pokémon with Aqua Bullet attack with bold 20 damage amount with description:

> This attack does 20 damage to 1 of your opponent's Benched Pokémon.
> (Don't apply Weakness and Resistance for Benched Pokémon.)

[image: Lapras with described attack]

What is not clear to me is whether this attack:

1. only does 20 damage to Benched Pokémon
2. it does 20 damage to Benched Pokémon and 20 to Active Pokémon

Is there special meaning to having large damage number printed next to attack?
Unfortunately damage amount is same, it would be clear if amounts would be different or if there would be no large damage amount printed.
I tried to compare with other cards and it did not help, more below.

For the first case I would expect it to not have large 20 damage next to attack. Like [Morpeko](https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/ss-series/swsh8/109/) - Target Spark (without large 30 next to attack):

> This attack does 30 damage to 1 of your opponent’s Pokémon. (Don’t
> apply Weakness and Resistance for Benched Pokémon.)

For the second case I would expect description to be worded like:

> This attack **also** does 20 damage...

Like [Steelix](https://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/ss-series/swsh8/139/) - Earthquake does:

> This attack also does 30 damage to each of your Benched Pokémon.
> (Don’t apply Weakness and Resistance for Benched Pokémon.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new era (new generation) is about to start in Pokémon TCG, standardized card texts are usually revised and improved. Your example falls into this category - since Sword & Shield era, the word *"also"* has been added to the attacks that do damage to both Active Pokémon and Benched Pokémon:

> *This attack **also** does X damage to 1 of your opponent's Benched Pokémon.*

Before that, all such attacks had just this shorter text – regardless if there was some damage done to Active Pokémon (the big number) or not:

> *This attack does X damage to 1 of your opponent's Benched Pokémon.*

---

Example cards from Sun & Moon era that have different amounts of damage done:

[image: Glaceon-GX (Ultra Prism)][image: Alolan Ninetales-GX (Lost Thunder)][image: Stoutland (Cosmic Eclipse)][image: Heatran (Lost Thunder)]

Example cards from Sword & Shield era with either variation of the attack text:

[image: Inteleon V (Fusion Strike)][image: Escavalier (Brilliant Stars)][image: Empoleon (Brilliant Stars)][image: Galarian Articuno (Evolving Skies)]